# When my app crashes on my phone I don't get force close and phone has to be restarted

Tags: java, android, adt

I have 2x Galaxy S3's, a work one and my own one, my personal one is rooted (to allow titanium backup to do it's thing).

When developing my app, if I'm using my work phone and it crashes on the phone it says XXX has crashed, click okay to force close.

However, on my phone it doesn't do that, it just crashes and I have to restart the phone.

Does anyone know the solution to this? It's quite infuriating at times.

Tom

```
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.directenquiries.assessment.tool/com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAssessment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAssessment.checkPhoto(AddAssessment.java:185)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAssessment.onResume(AddAssessment.java:358)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1188)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5258)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
12-06 14:55:05.643: E/AndroidRuntime(8025):     ... 12 more
```

**EDIT:** I can fix the problem with the app, I'm more trying to find out how to make my personal phone not need restarting every time an app crashes

Comment: Does anything show up in the logcat of the home phone?

Comment: AddAssessment line 185 is throwing null pointer. Check that area or post your code if you want us to help figure it out.

Comment: Sorry - I can fix the error with the app - that's not the issue. The issue is that the phone locks when ever theres an issue with the code, where as my work phone realises the app has crashes and forces the app closed. I don't want to restart my phone every time

Comment: Does anything follow the crash report itself? Something that might indicate why the phone itself is crashing? After the app crashes, is the app process still running?

Comment: Maybe the root has some effect on this.  My phone is rooted and does not crash in the manner but you are describing but I have noticed some other weird behavior since I rooted my phone.  For instance I cannot connect with adb connect <ip address:5555> anymore.

Comment: I literally can't do anything else with the phone when it crashes, the only thing I can do is restart the phone.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mawem-refw here's a video of it happening

Comment: Okay, the video looks grim. If you look at what's happening on the phone with DDMS, can you tell whether the app process goes away? Perhaps it is still alive and locking up the phone. See if you can use systrace or other tools to get some insight into what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the obvious answer is the phone's OS handles app crashes differently. One of the main reasons to root your phone is to get apps with more freedoms over the OS. In the stock android OS  each app gets it's own little sandbox to play in, and if it blows up the sandbox, the system just kicks it out, throws another layer of dirt on, and opens that spot up for another app.

I don't have a whole lot of experience with the non stock android world, but I'd guess that it's either that your rooted os doesn't wrest away the app's sand bucket when it has a seizure because it has permission to do whatever it wants, or perhaps there's something wrong with the OS utility for stoppping crashed apps in your rooted os.

Have you gotten a fatal crash from another app that isn't yours on your rooted phone where you would be able to force close it on your stock android phone? Does your application make use of any root only permissions or functions?